# Integrating Spring Boot with Flutter

Tags: flutter

So what I'm basically trying to do is, I've made an API using spring boot and now wanting to connect/fetch the data coming from the API into my flutter app. I tried watching a youtube video on it. I also got some idea but few lines were not clear due to which I could not make necessary changes into my app.

Below is the source code of home_screen.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:to_do_spring_integration/services/db_services.dart';

import '../models/task.dart';
import '../models/tasks_data.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  List<Task>? tasks;

  getTasks() async {
    tasks = await Db_services.getTasks();
    Provider.of<TasksData>(context, listen: false).tasks = tasks!;

    setState(() {
      
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getTasks();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return tasks == null
    ?
    const Scaffold(
      body: Center (
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
    )
    :
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Todo Tasks (${Provider.of<TasksData>(context).tasks.length})',
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

db_services.dart source code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:to_do_spring_integration/models/task.dart';
import 'package:to_do_spring_integration/services/globals.dart';

class Db_services {
  
  static Future<Task> addTask(String title) async {
    Map data = {
      "title": title,
    };

    var body = json.encode(data);
    var url = Uri.parse(baseURL + '/addDetails');

    http.Response response = await http.post(
      url, 
      headers: headers, 
      body: body,
    );

    // print(response.body);
    debugPrint(response.body);
    Map responseMap = jsonDecode(response.body);

    Task task = Task.fromMap(responseMap);

    return task;
  }

  static Future<List<Task>> getTasks() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(baseURL);

    http.Response response = await http.get(
      url, 
      headers: headers,
    );

    print(response.body);
    List responseList = jsonDecode(response.body);

    List<Task> tasks = [];

    for (Map taskMap in responseList) {
      Task task = Task.fromMap(taskMap);
      tasks.add(task);
    }

    return tasks;
  }

}
```

Below is source code of tasks_data.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:to_do_spring_integration/models/task.dart';
import 'package:to_do_spring_integration/services/db_services.dart';

class TasksData extends ChangeNotifier {

  List<Task> tasks = [];

  void addTask(String taskTitle) async {
    Task task = await Db_services.addTask(taskTitle);
    tasks.add(task);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateTask(Task task) {
    task.toggle();
    // Db_services.updateTask(task.id);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteTask(Task task) {
    tasks.remove(task);
    // Db_services.deleteTask(task.id);
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

The main confusion comes in the lines below (globals.dart)

```
const String baseURL = "https://10.0.2.2:8080";
const Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
```

In the video the baseURL is as the above line..
but I am not getting how do he got the '10.0.2.2' and I'm using a physical device from debugging and not an emulator.

The output I'm getting is just a circular progress bar.

If everything goes fine I should be getting as output the response.body printed in the console.

And help would be really appreciated!

Comment: baseURL I imagine should be what your spring boot service is being served on.

Comment: meaning it should be localhost:8080, which I already tried. But the problem is I'm using a physical device for debugging so it is still giving me the same issue.